# SailsJS where to define admin user if not exists on deployment

Tags: database, initialization, sails.js

Given I'm developing an API with authentication under SailsJS where do you think I must/should insert the code to create or initialize the admin user if not exists?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u need admin user for development, u can use bootstrap for that.

```
await User.create({ emailAddress: 'admin@example.com', fullName: 'Ryan Dahl', isSuperAdmin: true, password: await sails.helpers.passwords.hashPassword('abc123') }).fetch()
```

This is what Mike McNeil recommend in [example](https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/config/bootstrap.js).

Comment: I've seen few examples like this but something made me thought it wasn't the right place as if it was a mess. Thanks!!